# What is the value of $a + b$ if $a\sqrt{b} = BC$ in right triangle $\Delta ABC$?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

> In $\Delta ABC$, $\angle ABC = 90^\circ$ , $D$ is the midpoint of line
>   $BC$. Point $P$ is on $AD$ line. $PM$ & $PN$ are respectively
>   perpendicular on $AB$ & $AC$. $PM$ = $2PN$, $AB = 5$, $BC$ = $a\sqrt{b}$,
>   where $a, b$ are positive integers. $a+b$ = ?

Source: [Bangladesh Math Olympiad 2018 junior category](https://matholympiad.org.bd/).

I could not find any way to relate $PM$ = $2PN$ to this math.

Comment: This may not be unique.  What if $|BC|^2$ were $75$, do we take $a=1$ or $a=5$?  Or is the correct value amenable to $a=1$ only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Diagram]

$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle AMM' \sim \triangle PNM'$

$\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{NM'}{PN}$

$PM'=PM=2PN$

$NM'=\sqrt{(2PN)^2-PN^2}=PN\sqrt3$

$\frac{NM'}{PN}=\sqrt3$

$\frac{BC}{AB}=\sqrt3$

$BC=AB\sqrt3=5\sqrt3$

$a=5,b=3,\color{blue}{a+b=8}$

Comment: That's strange, I thought the sum would be 76.

Comment: @OscarLanzi As you pointed out, $5\sqrt3=1\sqrt{75}$, so $(a,b)=(1,75)$ technically qualifies.

Comment: Can someone please explain how PNM′ is similar to any one of the other two triangles?

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy They are all right triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\angle{BAC}=\alpha$$ then
$$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{PM}{5-PN}=-\frac{PN}{\frac{a}{2}-2PN}$$ so we get $$\frac{a}{2}+5=3PN$$ (1) and $$AD^2=5^2+\frac{a^2}{4}$$ so
$$\left(\frac{2PN}{\sin(\alpha)}+\frac{PN}{\cos(\alpha)}\right)^2=5^2+\frac{a^2}{4}$$ and for $PN$ we have $$PN=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{a}{2}+5\right)$$ and $$\cos^2(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\tan^2(\alpha)+1)}$$ and $$\sin^2(\alpha)=\frac{\tan^2(\alpha)}{1+\tan^2(\alpha)}$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

We can think that $B=(0,0)$. Then $A=(0,5)$ and $C=(a\sqrt{b},0)$.

Then we have that $D=(\frac{a\sqrt{b}}{2},0)$.

Since $P$ is in $AD$, $P=(0,5)+\lambda_1 (a\sqrt{b},-10)$.

Now, as we can see in the picture, we do not know where $N$ and $M$ are. But by what you said, we have two options for each one:

$N_1= (0,5)+\lambda_2(a\sqrt{b},-5)$

$N_2= (0,0)+\lambda_3(a\sqrt{b},0) = (\lambda_3 \cdot a\sqrt{b},0)$

$M_1= (0,0)+\lambda_4(0,5)=(0,\lambda_4 \cdot 5)$

$M_2= (0,5)+\lambda_5(a\sqrt{b},-5)$

Now, we have to play computating $PM$ and $PN$ and using your relation.

[image]

Comment: I will edit it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Draw the triangle as instructed.  $M$ and $N$ are taken to be the feet if the respective perpendiculars to the triangle's sides, $M$ on $AB$ and $N$ on $AC$.

Draw $DN'$ parallel to $PN$ with $N'$ also on $AC$.  Then $\triangle AMP ~ \triangle ABD$ and $\triangle APB ~ \triangle ADN'$, forcing $|PM|/|PN|=|BD|/|DN'|=|CD|/|DN'|=2$.  Then right $\triangle DN'C$ has a hypoteneyse/leg ratio of $2:1$ hence $\angle C$ measures $30°$.

It follows that right $\triangle ABC$ with a $30°$ angle at $C$ also has a $2:1$ ratio of the hypotenuse to the shorter leg, therefore its hypotenuse is $10$ and $|BC|=5\sqrt{3}=1\sqrt{75}$.  And the solution is nonunique!  C'mon man!